# Помогите вывести все посты со списком тегов

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите вывести все посты со списком тегов, надеюсь на скрине будет видно, и ясно как устроена баа данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Андрей, покажите, что вы уже сделали, и расскажите, чем вас не устраивает ваш результат.

Comment: @АндрейШостик, картинки вместо текста тут не приветствуются.

Comment: @Visman, спасибо, учту

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT *
    FROM posts p
         JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
         JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
ORDER BY t.tag_name
```